# What resolution of image should I use?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to use some images in my game. And I will se them from sqlite database, randomly. They will not be displayed in full screen, maybe 80% of the screen, I have to have some buttons below the image. I know when I set background to my apps I need to have several resolutions, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi, where for example xhdpi is 640X480. But I will have only one image of a kind in my database. What resolution should I use to look good on any phone?

Answer (score 1):

Question like "resolution should I use to look good on any phone" indicate you are not familiar with the way Android deals with screen, because answer for such question is simply "use right resolution". And mind density. Read here: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Well lets say I am familiar with the way Android deals with screen. Now, why would I ask this question in the first place? Of course I am not that familiar with the way Android deals with screen.

Comment: So, @marjanbaz, then your answer is right here: read the link above? I don't think WebnetMobile is trying to attack you; they're trying to *help* you. Your comment is out of place here, I feel.

Comment: Yes, I started reading that moment.

Comment: So, I need to supply multiple resource, basically. And I can't do that. This is very confusing. Especially cause I don't need fullscreen bitmap.

Comment: Can I use 480X640 bitmap at hdpi? Or maybe it's better idea to use that resolution with mdpi? I can only have one instance of an image, cause I will be using sqlite database to retrieve images.